# What are current ADA standards / requirements on images?

Tags: legal, content, website-design, accessibility

I am wondering what ADA (American disabilities act not dental association) currently requires when it comes to images and other things not easily read by webpage "readers". I am currently trying to make sure a website meets all required standards so nobody gets yelled at or in any legal trouble if someone with disabilities were to attempt to read the page.

Note: I have looked these up but I have found odd legal terms. Is there a more simple explanation such as "Must have alt tags on all images and navigation bars must do something something something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALT Tags are normally a must for any website trying to achieve good accessibility never mind the ADA. On the [ADA website you can see that within their guidelines](http://www.ada.gov/websites2.htm) they recommend alt tags as well as using long descriptions which is `longdesc=""`, so this answers your main question. With the concern of the other question about legal matters, I'm not sure which obligation your under to provide such accessibility but if your website does require such features then the ADA uses the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) as their footprint and you should read everything in that link provided as well as interesting stories why people need such features.

EDIT: Navigation Bars should not need to use ALT tags since they should be background elements and not `img src=" "` backgrounds are not considered apart of Accessiblity, only embeds of using `<img src="">` related to the information provided on the page... Besides nowadays you shouldn't use navigation img srcs as that's just bad designing.